# Force update in install4j application

Tags: java, linux, windows, install4j

I'm developing an install4j application for Windows and Linux. I use the updater with silent version check to check for new versions on each launch of the application. The issue is that if the user presses cancel on any step of the update process the application starts. I don't want the user to be able to use the application at all without first updating. Can this be done in install4j?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installer applications have a "Default execution mode" property. For the updater application, you can set it to "Unattended mode with progress dialog". In that case, the user cannot cancel anything.

Comment: The only problem with this solution for me is the fact that my update requires PC restart. So i have to ask the user does he want to restart his PC now or later and that's not possible in unattended mode. Anyway around this?

Comment: You can add another (empty) custom installer application where you just call context.triggerReboot(true) in a "Run script" action in the startup sequence, without any other screens. Then you can call that custom installer application at the end of the installer.