# Update Downloader with silent Version check -> GUI Style Layout

Tags: java, install4j

Our application currently has "Background update downloader" configured for the update checks and installation. We have a few problems in this approach with the User community and we are working on making the update transparent to the User. To this end we are trying out the "Update downloader with the silent version check".

However, here we have the same or similar as question as discussed in

[Force update in install4j application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708769/force-update-in-install4j-application)

We want to remove the "Cancel" button in the GUI Style Layout. However, it is possible for us to change the contents of the "Form" but not the layout itself.

The answer was to use the "Unattended mode with progress dialog". My question would be would moving from the GUI Style to "Unattended mode with progress dialog" result in not presenting the user the Dialog (attached) where he/she can select the download directory, show the old and new version that is available?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question would be would moving from the GUI Style to "Unattended mode with progress dialog" result in not presenting the user the Dialog (attached) where he/she can select the download directory, show the old and new version that is available?

Yes, "Unattended mode with progress dialog" just shows a progress dialog and none of the screens.

If you want to show the screens and just hide the "Cancel" button, that is possible by setting the "Post-activation script" property of all screens of the update downloader to

```
context.getWizardContext().setControlButtonVisible(ControlButtonType.CANCEL, false);
```

Comment: Thank You Ingo Kegel....This worked...However, also noticed the following behaviour. Any changes to the Forms also requires a uninstall and install. ie. Have the application installed without any changes to the Forms. Deliver an update with the change to the Forms.e.g In this case hide the "Cancel" button. This update does not take in the newly changed Form but rather the old one.

Comment: The update downloader is part of the installation, not of the new installer. This means that the next update will still use the old update downloader.